# good resources for grok patterns for python log file

Tags: python-2.7, logging, logstash, logstash-grok

I want to use logtash for parsing python log files , where can i find the resources that help me in doing that. For example:

> 20131113T052627.769: myapp.py: 240: INFO: User Niranjan Logged-in

In this I need to capture the time information and also some data information.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem/need. I couldn't really find a solution to this. No available grok patterns really matched the python logging output, so I simply went ahead and wrote a custom grok pattern which I've added naively into `patterns/grok-patterns`.

```
DATESTAMP_PYTHON %{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY} %{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND},%{INT}
```

The logstash configuration I wrote gave me nice fields.

- **@timestamp**
- **level**
- **message**

Added some extra field which I called **pymodule** which should show you the python module that was producing the log entry.

My logstash configuration file looks like this (*ignore the sincedb_path this is simple a manner of forcing logstash to read the entire log file everytime you run it*):

```
input {                                                                                                                                                                                                
    file {                                                                                                                                                                                             
        path => "/tmp/logging_file"                                                                                                                                                                            
        start_position => "beginning"                                                                                                                                                                  
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"                                                                                                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                                                                                                                      

filter {                                                                                                                                                                                               
    grok {                                                                                                                                                                                             
        match => [                                                                                                                                                                                     
            "message",                                                                                                                                                                                             "%{DATESTAMP_PYTHON:timestamp} - %{DATA:pymodule} - %{LOGLEVEL:level} - %{GREEDYDATA:logmessage}"                                                                                                  ]                                                                                                                                                                                              
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                  

    mutate {                                                                                                                                                                                           
        rename => [ "logmessage", "message" ]                                                                                                                                                          
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                  

    date {                                                                                                                                                                                             
        timezone => "Europe/Luxembourg"                                                                                                                                                                
        locale => "en"                                                                                                                                                                                 
        match => [ "timestamp" , "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" ]                                                                                                                                           
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                                                                                                                      

output {                                                                                                                                                                                               
    stdout {                                                                                                                                                                                           
        codec => json                                                                                                                                                                                  
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                  
}
```

**Please note that**

> I give absolutely no guarantee that this is the best or even an
>   slightly acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Our Python log file has a slightly different format:

```
[2014-10-08 19:05:02,846] (6715) DEBUG:Our debug message here
```

So I was able to create a configuration file without any need for special patterns:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/path/to/python.log"
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}
filter {
    grok {
        match => [
            "message",                                                                                                                                                                                             "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\] \(%{DATA:pyid}\) %{LOGLEVEL:level}\:%{GREEDYDATA:logmessage}"                                                                                                  ]
    }
    mutate {
        rename => [ "logmessage", "message" ]
    }
    date {
        timezone => "Europe/London"
        locale => "en"
        match => [ "timestamp" , "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" ]
    }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => localhost
  }
  stdout { 
      codec => rubydebug 
  }
}
```

And this seems to work fine.